# Increasing div width and height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my webpage there are [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) widgets which have multiple images in them. Images can be added with `+` button.The widgets can be resized as well.

I am displaying these images inside div with `class=imagewrap` and the images have class `images` with them.

**My overall aim**

I want to increase/decrease the div width and height dynamically as the widget is resized.Also I want the aspect ration of the image to be preserved.

**What I have achieved/tried so far**

I currently have declared the div `width` and `height` as `80px` and I am able to fit all the images perfectly in them maintaining its aspect ratio.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wo13h8sg/)

```css
.imagewrap {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative; 
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.images {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
     <div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src='+ images[j] +' title="' + titles[j]+ '"><input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added Flex CSS to flex the content. then added min-width and height. then added `'img-responsive'` class to `<img class='images'>` using JQuery `addClass()`. let me know if this does it for you

## UPDATED:

```js
var gridster;
//Initializing Gridster
gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
  widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100],
  widget_margins: [5, 5],
  helper: 'clone',
  serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
    return {
      images: $w.find('.imagenames').val().trim(),
      title: $w.find('.hoverinformation').val().trim(),
      col: wgd.col,
      row: wgd.row,
      size_x: wgd.size_x,
      size_y: wgd.size_y
    }
  },
  resize: {
    enabled: true
  }
}).data('gridster');



//JSON which I get from backend

var json = [{
    "images": "https://png.icons8.com/metro/2x/boy.png,https://png.icons8.com/metro/2x/boy.png,https://png.icons8.com/metro/2x/chapel.png",
    "title": "AB,DE,EF",
    "infoonwidgets": "Some Info",
    "col": 1,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }

];

//Loop which runs over JSON to generate <li> elements in HTML

for (var index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
  var images = json[index].images.split(',');
  var titles = json[index].title.split(',');
  var imageOutput = "";

  for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
    imageOutput += '<div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src=' + images[j] + ' title="' + titles[j] + '"> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div></div>';
  }

  gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="addmorebrands" style="float: left;">+</button><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><textarea class="info-on-widgets">' + json[index].infoonwidgets + '</textarea><div class="content"><div class="row">' + imageOutput + '</div></div><textarea class="imagenames">' + json[index].images + '</textarea><textarea class="hoverinformation">' + json[index].title + '</textarea></li>', json[index].size_x, json[index].size_y, json[index].col, json[index].row);
}

function trimChar(string, charToRemove) {
  while (string.charAt(0) == charToRemove) {
    string = string.substring(1);
  }

  while (string.charAt(string.length - 1) == charToRemove) {
    string = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
  }

  return string;
}

function updateTextarea(imageNames, imageSrc) {
  var imageNamesValue = imageNames.val();
  imageNamesValue = imageNamesValue.replace(imageSrc, '');
  imageNamesValue = trimChar(imageNamesValue, ',');
  imageNamesValue = imageNamesValue.trim();
  imageNames.val(imageNamesValue.replace(/,,/g, ","));
}

//Function to delete an image from widget

$(document).on('click', '.removediv', function() {
  var imageDelete = $(this).closest('div.imagewrap');
  var imgTag = imageDelete.find('img');
  var imageTitle = imgTag.attr('title');
  var imageSrc = imgTag.attr('src');

  var textareaName = $(this).closest('li').find('.imagenames');
  var textareaTitle = $(this).closest('li').find('.hoverinformation');

  updateTextarea(textareaName, imageSrc);
  updateTextarea(textareaTitle, imageTitle);
  //Here I want that will remove the content from both the textareas
  imageDelete.remove();
});



//Function to delete a widget
$(document).on("click", ".delete-widget-button", function() {
  var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
  gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
});

//Adding Images from Modal
var parentLI;
var selectedImageSRC = "";

$(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
  parentLI = $(this).closest('li');
  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
});

$('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function() {
  parentdiv = $(this).closest('div.outerdiv');
  if (parentdiv.hasClass('preselect')) {

    parentdiv.removeClass('preselect');
    selectedImageSRC = selectedImageSRC.replace($(this).attr('src'), "");
    selectedImageSRC = trimChar(selectedImageSRC, ',');
    selectedImageSRC = (selectedImageSRC.replace(/,,/g, ","));
    console.log("In remove");
    console.log(selectedImageSRC);
    console.log("Parent Div in remove");
    console.log(parentdiv);
  } else {

    parentdiv.addClass('preselect');

    if (selectedImageSRC === '') {

      selectedImageSRC += $(this).attr('src');

    } else {

      selectedImageSRC += ',' + $(this).attr('src');
    }

    console.log("In add");
    console.log(selectedImageSRC);
    console.log("Parent Div in Add");
    console.log(parentdiv);
  }
});

$('#add-image').click(function() {

  console.log("In add image");
  console.log(selectedImageSRC);
  var multipleImageSRC = "";
  multipleImageSRC = selectedImageSRC.split(',');
  console.log("Splitted Images");
  console.log(multipleImageSRC);
  var multipleImages = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < multipleImageSRC.length; j++) {
    multipleImages += '<div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src="' + multipleImageSRC[j] + '" title="Manual Addition"> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div>'
    console.log("Multiple Images SRC");
    console.log(multipleImages);
  }


  parentLI.append(multipleImages);



  var imageNameValue = parentLI.children('.imagenames').val();
  var imageTitleValue = parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val();

  //Loop for Updating Textarea with ImageNames
  var imageNameInTextarea = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < multipleImageSRC.length; j++) {

    imageNameInTextarea += multipleImageSRC[j].replace("/static/images/brands/", "") + ",";

  }

  //To remove last ',' after the names
  imageNameInTextarea = trimChar(imageNameInTextarea, ',');
  console.log(imageNameInTextarea);

  //Loop calculating lenght of number of images added and correspondingly putting "Manual Addition"

  manualAddition = "";

  for (var j = 0; j < multipleImageSRC.length; j++) {

    manualAddition += "Manual Addition" + ",";

  }

  //To remove last ',' after the names
  manualAddition = trimChar(manualAddition, ',');

  console.log("Manual Textarea");
  console.log(manualAddition);

  if (imageNameValue === '') {
    parentLI.children('.imagenames').val(imageNameInTextarea);
  } else {
    parentLI.children('.imagenames').val(imageNameValue + ',' + imageNameInTextarea);
  }


  if (imageTitleValue === '') {
    parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val(manualAddition);
  } else {
    parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val(imageTitleValue + ',' + manualAddition);
  }


  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
  removeclasses()



});


function removeclasses() {
  //Removing preselect class from all the div's when close button or add brand button is clicked.

  a = $('div .outerdiv').removeClass('preselect');
  selectedImageSRC = "";
  console.log(a);

}
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('img[class*="images"]').addClass('img-responsive');
});
```

```css
.info-on-widgets {
  width: 90%;
}

.removediv {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1%;
  top: 1%;
}

.preselect {
  background: lightgreen
}

.modal-body {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.outerdiv {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imagenames,
.hoverinformation,
.widget-color {
  display: none;
}

/* CSS for increasing image aspect ratio when resized */

.content {}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.imagewrap {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}

.images {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/demos/assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.gridster/0.5.6/jquery.gridster.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="gridster">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.gridster/0.5.6/jquery.gridster.min.js"></script>
  <!--  <li> from JSON are placed here -->
  <ul>

  </ul>
</div>



<!--  Declaration of Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add Icons</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="removeclasses()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!--  Images which I retrieve from backend for now they are 
      hardcoded paths and actually are dynamic(No fixed number)-->


        <div class="outerdiv"><img src="https://cdnd.icons8.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Run-Command-100.png"></div>
        <div class="outerdiv"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/2x/chapel.png"></div>
        <div class="outerdiv"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/2x/boy.png"></div>
        <div class="outerdiv"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/2x/wacom-tablet.png"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="removeclasses()">Close</button>
        <button id="add-image" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Image</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Read more about Flex CSS (AKA: Flexbox CSS) at: [Typical use cases of Flexbox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Typical_Use_Cases_of_Flexbox)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Typical_Use_Cases_of_Flexbox)

Comment: Please note you can further manipulate your output by adding CSS Media Queries like media (min-width: 540px){flex-direction: row nowrap;} and further manipulation is possible by targeting selector attributes like .content[type="row"]{max-width: 100%;}

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you have taken to solve the problem I am facing.Let me try out what you have suggested.I will need to go over the CSS flex as well to see If it entirely works for me.But still a lot of helpful direction you have given

Comment: Can you tell me when I say `min-width:80px`; and `min-height:80px` and also specify the `width: 30%;height: 30%;`What does that means

Comment: sorry read it wrong. you are specifying that the min-width: will always be 80px no matter what. however, you want it to be at 30% of what ever resolution you are at. where this may be a problem is when 80px is more then width of page. then you will get horizontal scroll bar

Answer (score 3):

I would instead use the image as a background, and use `background-size:cover;` to keep the photo proportioned as much as possible. This way you could specify the width and height of the image div in percentages, and the photo inside would scale. You could `background-position:center;` it so that way if the frame gets too tall or wide, only a slight portion of the edges will get cut off.

So for your image-wrap div, give it the proper size that you want and apply the background to it. You can use `'+ images[j] +'` as well on the div, by making it an inline style that's applied. So: `<div style="background-image=url('+images[j]+');">`

```css
.imagewrap {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative; 
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  background-image:url(http://www.placecage.com/200/300);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
.images {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
     <div class="imagewrap"><input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div></div>
```

Comment: How do I fit that in my existing model.I am completely new to web development.Whatever I have done so far is with help of SO and other online resources

Comment: `.imagewrap` is the div which contains image in it.It is around each widget.By doing `Inspect Element` you can see that each image is in the div `.imagewrap`

Comment: I concur this could work. only drawback is clipping. if that is not an issue this will work. I have seen me do it.

Comment: Ahh, so it's getting added dynamically. I didn't realize that your images where icons.  This might not be the best method for you then.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Yeah I am getting images dynamically and I cant put it in  CSS

Comment: JQuery to add classes dynamically is the best possible resolution. then you can CSS the crud out of them $(".image").addClass("flex-image");

Comment: @blayderunner123  I am not getting what you trying to tell

Comment: @PaigeMeinke I tried with  `min-width:80px;
  min-height:80px; width: 30%;height: 30%;` But that does not seem to be working.Or atleast please I feel Correct me If I am wrong  Here https://jsfiddle.net/wo13h8sg/1/

Comment: I feel that it is just increasing the div to a larger extent when the widget size in increased.But the image doesnt seems to increase to that extent.It is wasting a lot of space on widget

Comment: @NewBie The reason why they aren't growing is because that's as large as the image is. 52px by 52px. Max-width effects the image itself, so the largest the image can be at max-width:100% is 52px wide. Width:100% will take up the width of the parent it is in.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Okay got it .Means it wont grow beyond the actual image size.No matter how big is the div.

Comment: Also can you tell me when I say `min-width:80px;`  and `min-height:80px` and also specify the `width: 30%;height: 30%;`What does that means

Answer (score -3):

width and height in percent commands, maybe you combine this with a javascript, who gives you per tick or other event the values back in the css

(without proof)

```
window.onresize = function () {

    var xx = document.getElementById('imagewrap').offsetWidth;  // i think it is a html-dom-id
    var yy = document.getElementById('imagewrap').offsetHeight;  // i think it is a html-dom-id  

    var x = 10;
    var y = 10;

    var xx = xx + x;
    var yy = yy + y;

    document.getElementById('imagewrap').offsetWidth = xx;
    document.getElementById('imagewrap').offsetHeight = yy;

   }
```

Comment: Perhaps add some code as an example? And elaborate?

Comment: sry, i'm only a german software architect who precised the first comment and i became 4 negatives

Comment: @6H057845H dont worry.. just update your answer with some code & explaination.. upvoted for starter

Comment: sry for this .. i'm not fast enought for this. for the ratio i maybe make a min-size and give in a resize-event the div a new dimension (x,y) + margin for the guarantee of the ratio ... but maybe, i did'nt understand his problem.

Comment: maybe Sass (Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets) is a alternative for him